# Graph Theory: Remove nodes, but create new vertices to keep graph connected

Tags: graph, theory, directed-graph

I have a requirement to remove nodes of a certain type, but I want the graph to remain connected.

It is a directed non-cyclic graph.

Example:

[image]

I want to run an algorithm to remove all "B" nodes and keep only "A", which results into the following:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a graph theory algorithm that can solve this problem?

Comment: Looking at your example, are you considering the case where A1 could be B0? If you don't handle that separately, then you will end up with an unconnected graph.

Comment: @PeterAbolins: Fair question: The result can then be an unconnected graph. If A1 is B0, I want the output to be A3->A4 only. A2 will not have a vertex pointing to it. I guess i don't really want the graph to be connected, I want only vertices between A type.

Comment: If my solution was of assistance, do you want to mark it as an answer? If not, let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a lot of years since I worked with algorithms and graph-theory, so if my answer appears a bit rusty, I apologize in advance.

```
Create a worklist W.
Add r, the root node, to W.
While W is not empty:
    Remove the first entry from W; call it s.
    For each of s's children:
        Add it to W.
    If s is of type B
        In the graph, set s's parent to be the parent of s's children.
        Remove s from the graph.
```

For the case where the root node is of type B, I am thinking it would be possible to create a dummy root (of type <> B) as a parent of the original root node. While the final graph would still be connected, it would depend on what your requirements are, since the dummy root would need to be removed. In your example, A2 would be an orphan, and would be discarded. But you could also end up with two or more disconnected graphs: A2 -> A5; A3 -> A4 (eg)

Comment: I ended up using your algorithm. I made  a change in the step where you set s's parent to be parent of s's children. s can have more than one parent. So I create edges from s's parent(s) to s's children. Thanks for the help.